# Scala Compiler Java Null Pointer Exception

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I'm trying to run a spring boot project which has scala simulation file. I have Scala 2.13.12 and Java 21 in my system. I installed the Scala 2021.1.22 plugin in my intellij 2021.1.2. My intellij seems to be showing the below error message and therefore i'm unable to build the project. I have tried to invalid cache/restart Intellij, build, rebuild project. But I'm still facing the same issue. Could you let me know what might be going wrong?

[image]

This is my intellij Scala compiler settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Click on the line "rebuild failed" rather than "nullpointerexception", it might give more details.

Comment: I have added this screenshot in the question now.

Comment: Let's try to localize the problem, whether this is an issue with this specific project or with Scala plugin installation. Can you build your project outside IDE (sbt/Maven/etc)? Can you build other Scala project (hello-world) in the IDE?

Comment: Current Scala plugin is 2023.3.679, current IntelliJ IDEA is 2023.3.4. Java 21 was released in September 2023. Your Scala plugin **2021**.1.22 could be too old.

Comment: @DmytroMitin Yes, you're right. I updated my Intellij to the latest version which automatically updated the Scala plugin and it seems to have solved the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was in combination of outdated Scala plugin and latest JDK. Resolved with installing latest IDE + Scala plugin.

The stacktrace of NPE hinted that this could be an issue with the Scala plugin.